# Is it possible to bind multiple folders in Docker?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to bind multiple folders in Docker?
For example, like ports:

```
-p 3000:3000 -p 3022:22
```

The idea seems like:

```
-v path:path -v path2:path2
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No problem at all. 
You can specify files and directories like in this example taken from a tomcat container to blend in certificates. (`:ro` is optional for read only)

```
-v $(pwd)/secret-files/certificates/verisign.keystore:$CONFIG_PATH/certificates/verisign.keystore:ro \
-v $(pwd)/secret-files/certificates/fuse/:$CONFIG_PATH/certificates/fuse/:ro \
```

Comment: I would like my docker container to pick up the path from the variable configured in spring application.yml. How do  I go about it please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498509/how-to-read-and-write-to-host-filesystem-from-springbootapachecamel-running-ins

Answer (score 3):

Docker allows mounting (or binding) multiple folders. Here is the Docker documentation which clearly mention this : [link](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)

> -v, --volume=[] Bind mount a volume (e.g., from the host: -v /host:/container, from Docker: -v /container)
>
> You can add a data volume to a container using the -v flag with the docker  create and docker run command. You can use the -v  multiple times to mount multiple data volumes.

Example (from what I do) :

```
docker run -v /opt/rpms:/opt/rpms/ -v /export/centos6_1/app/logs:/export/centos6_1/app/logs -t -i centos6_1 /bin/bash
```